# How to put a spy on clearInterval() in sinon?

Tags: reactjs, sinon, sinon-chai

I want to test that `clearInterval()` has been called on `componentWillUnmount()`.  How do I set a spy on `clearInterval()`?

```
it("should unmount", () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<MessageLoaderWrapper messageList={messageList} />);
    wrapper.unmount();
    expect(wrapper.find(".tabs-infinite-loader--message").length).to.equal(0);
});
```

Currently testing that a className is no longer there; but really should be testing that `clearInterval()` was called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Global functions can be spied on `window` or `global`, depending on the environment, e.g.:

```
sinon.spy(global, 'clearInterval');
...
expect(clearInterval).to.have.been.calledOnce;
```

Comment: I guess need that to be coupled with equivalent of shouldHaveBeenCalled on the object if they have it, not sure how sinon works

Comment: @Rikin That's correct. This depends on how spy assertions are configured. In this case it looks that it's Sinon+Chai.

Comment: Thank you. Might be a good idea to show the best practice of saving the spy and restoring it after the test.

Comment: @NotoriousWebmaster This depends on your setup. The best practice is to use Sinon plugin for your test runner, which does this automatically. It's not listed, is it Mocha? See https://www.npmjs.com/package/mocha-sinon